# Use Data from 2 Lists in ASP.Net Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, repeater

Is it possible, to bind two Lists to a Repeater(which creates a Table), to use Data from both Lists?
I have a List with actions and a List with Users. I would like to display some Information about the Action, and about the User who issued the Action. Can I combine the Information about the Action with the Information about the User?

Here's a Sketch of the Table, how it should look like:

ID | Time | Info about Action | UserID | Full Name  |Info about User

Jopi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than binding two data sources and trying to have the `Repeater` sort it out, what you need to do is combine the data into a single item *before* you bind it to the repeater.

As to how you do that, it will depend on how your data is structured.

If the item at the same indexes of both lists are the items that "belong together" then you could just use `Zip`.

```
var query = actions.Zip(users, (a,b)=> new CombinedStructure(a,b));
```

You could either create a new custom type to store the data that needs to be in each displayed row, or use an anonymous type and assign each field manually.

If the indexes don't correspond then you'll likely need a join

```
var query = from action in actions
            join user in users
            on user.ID = action.UserID
            select ...
```

Answer (score 1):

No, but you could use LINQ to join them:

- [joining two sets in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867567/joining-two-sets-in-linq)
- http://geekswithblogs.net/JustinGreenwood/archive/2012/03/15/how-to-join-two-collections-with-linq.aspx

And bind the result.